# Не запускать второй экземпляр скрипта

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Приветствую!

Допустим, существует некий скрипт

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    print("hello!")
    sleep(100)
```

который запускается по `cron` каждую минуту в centos6. Подскажите пожалуйста, как предотвратить запуск ещё одного экземпляра скрипта, если первый ещё не завершил работу?

Пока нашёл только вот такую штуку

```
from pid import PidFile

with PidFile():
  do_something()
```

Но увы, её нет в стандартных репах centos6. Я буду очень благодарен за решение, которое работает "из коробки". Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать файл/переменную окружения: при запуске проверять на пустоту/False, затем ставить True, а по завершению возвращать False.

Comment: С помощью ``psutil`` проверить, если ли скрипт  в процессах. Если есть, ничего не делать, если нет - запустить скрипт.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/380870/4827341

Answer (score 2):

к примеру, можно блокировать сам файл со скриптом (ну, чтоб не заводить отдельных файлов) с помощью функции [flock() из fcntl](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import fcntl, sys, os
from time import sleep

fp = open(os.path.realpath(__file__), 'r')

try:
    fcntl.flock(fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError:
    print('неужели другой мой экземпляр всё ещё работает?')
    sys.exit(0)

print('я единственный и неповторимый!!11')
sleep(2)
```

---

проверка.

если между запуском первого и второго экземпляра меньше двух секунд (время работы первого экземпляра), то второй (третий…) экземпляр получит исключение при попытке блокировки:

```
$ ./s.py & sleep 1; ./s.py
[1] 26327
я единственный и неповторимый!!11
неужели другой мой экземпляр всё ещё работает?
```

если же больше, то оба запуска пройдут успешно:

```
$ ./s.py & sleep 3; ./s.py
[1] 26382
я единственный и неповторимый!!11
[1]+  Done                    ./s.py
я единственный и неповторимый!!11
```

Comment: `fp = open(os.path.realpath(__file__), 'r')` а это вообще законно? :) Я пока так сделал `fp = open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), '{}.lock'.format(os.path.basename(__file__))), 'w')` - но тут, как Вы заметили, надо файлик создавать. Может кто-нить ещё чего интересного предложит :)

Comment: *а это вообще законно?* — меня пока не расстреляли. и [вот этот товарищ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7258093/4827341) два дня назад был всё ещё жив. // а что вас вообще смущает? файл со скриптом — это самый обыкновенный файл. главное, что вряд ли какому-то другому процессу, кроме запущенного вами же, может понадобится делать блокировку именно на этом файле.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью модуля **`sys`** мы можем получить название текущего файла. А используя модуль [**`subprocess`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) можем посмотреть количество процессов с таким именем.

```
import subprocess
import sys

# имя текущего процесса
name = sys.argv[0].split('/')[-1]
# команда для поиска процессов с таким именем
com = 'pgrep -f ' + name

# запускаем команду
p = subprocess.Popen([com], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
# берём результат
res = p.communicate()[0]
# в Питоне 3.* результат – байты, его нужно привести к строке
if isinstance(res, bytes):
    res = res.decode("utf-8")
# достаём из текста список процессов
res = [str(x) for x in res.split('\n') if len(x) > 0]

# расходимся, если процесс уже запущен
if len(res) > 0:
    print('Already running!')

# иначе делаем полезную работу
# например, немного ждём
else:
    import time
    print('Sleep...')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('Exit!')
```